# webpack2 cjs require log messages

Tags: webpack-2

I'm seeing these log messages when starting web dev server in webpack2

```
[434] ./src/main/rootStore.js 1.86 kB {0} [built]
       cjs require src/main/rootStore [392] ./src/main/index.jsx 15:17-46
```

I thought webpack2 uses es6 modules directly and doesn't need CJS conversion. Does anyone know what this 'cjs require' means?

Thanks.